# Invert Y-axis on image on python before plot

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, plot

Hello and thank you for your help, my problem is this:
I am working on python using satellite images and shapefile, both were original on geographical projection and passed it to pixel so when I plot first the Landsat image is OK, i don't mind the position of axis here, but when i add to the 2D array the shapefile, the areas (in this case), are upside down (I know why because of  location of the origin of a image is different from a normal plot.

I try to applied origin='lower' but that is to the final result, when both image and shapefile are added and is not what i want. Also try .reverse(), [::-1]  to the array of Y axis before adding to the image but no good result, hope you can help me.

This is the plot of areas in the jungle (of Peru if you are wondering) and blue box is the area i want to show on Landsat (satellite image):

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXJyH.jpg

This is the area converted to pixels and added to the satellite image, look how is inverted due the location of the origin compared it to the first image
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bOVN.jpg

thanks for your help.

EDIT: this is kind the code (is really extensive, so the most important is this

```
#THIS IS THE BORDER AREA EXTRACTED FROM THE SHAPEFILE AND ALREADY CONVERTED TO PIXEL

mos_ext = mos_total[(m0):(m1+1), int(minXY[0]):int(maxXY[0]+1 )]

#I just dilate a little for better visualization
mask3 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (6, 6))
mos_ext=cv2.dilate(mos_ext, mask3, iterations=1)

#This IS THE LANDSAT IMAGE
im_ls2=mask_bi3.copy()

ADDING THE BORDERS OF AREA (WHAT IS SHOWN ON RED ON THE SECOND IMAGE)
coorde=np.where(mos_ext==255)
im_ls2[coorde[0], coorde[1], 0] = 255
im_ls2[coorde[0], coorde[1], 1] = 0
im_ls2[coorde[0], coorde[1], 2] = 0


fig3, axes3 = plt.subplots(1)
axes3.imshow(im_ls2, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, add some code so we get a better sense of what you've tried and how we might help.

Comment: already added :)

Comment: In order to reverse an image you can use `np.flipud(imagearray)`. Is this what you did and what did not work? If so, it would still help to know what the respective results were (they should be different in any case) and in how far they are not what you expect. Mind that we are not experts in peruvian geography! ;-)

Comment: Actually I tried that before but apparently in a wrong line, now I applied to mos_ext and it worked :D
Thanks a lot